# Implement Blur over parts of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, opengl-es, core-graphics

How can I implement the image below pragmatically - meaning the digits can change at runtime or even be replaced with a movie?

[image]

Comment: What are you working with? Is this whole thing in openGL or is this UI? Is the blurred part static or can be anything? If openGL are you using ES2? ...

Comment: I would of course prefer to work as high level as possible but OpenGL if needed (ES2). The aim is to have a blur filter which can overlay any view/layer

Answer (score 1):

Just add a blurred UIView on top of your thing.

For example...make a UIImage of your desired view size, blur it using [CIFilter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003960) and then add it to your view .It should achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271016/fast-blur-on-ios) is generally the same question and is answered by quite a few methods.. Anyway I would propose 1 more:

Get the image from UIView

```
+ (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([layer frame].size);
    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return outputImage;
}
```

rather yet play around a bit with this to get the desired part of the view as the image. Now create a new view and add to it image views (with the image you get from layer). Then move the centers of the image views to achieve gaussian algorithm and take the image from this layer again and place it back on the original view.

Moving the center should be defined by radius fragment (I'd start with .5f) and resample range.

```
for(int i=1; i<resampleCount; i++) {
view1.center = CGPointMake(view1.center.x + radiusFragment*i, view1.center.y);
view2.center = CGPointMake(view2.center.x - radiusFragment*i, view2.center.y);
view3.center = CGPointMake(view3.center.x, view3.center.y + radiusFragment*i);
view4.center = CGPointMake(view4.center.x, view4.center.y - radiusFragment*i);
//add the subviews
}
//get the image from view
```

All the subviews need to have alpha set to `1.0f/(resampleCount*4)`

This method might not be the fastest but it would be extremely easy to implement and if you can pimp the radius and resample range to minimum fragments it should do pretty well.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I would like to be able to replace the part under the blur with anything, including video. With video extracting images will not be feasible.

Answer (score -1):

use a UIView whith white background and decrease the alpha property

```
blurView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:0.3]
```

Comment: This will not blur the view.